# jQuery slider does not stop at once

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I am wondering why my jQuery slider does not stop immediately after event: mouseover. There is a delay, could somebody help me  with this issue? 
Here you have my code: https://jsfiddle.net/jrswchkp/1/

```
    $(function() {

  var $clientcarousel = $('#clients-list');
  var clients = $clientcarousel.children().length;
  var clientwidth = (clients * 400); // 140px width for each client item 
  $clientcarousel.css('width', clientwidth);

  var rotating = true;
  var clientspeed = 0;
  var seeclients = setInterval(rotateClients, clientspeed);


  function rotateClients() {
    if (rotating != false) {
      var $first = $('#clients-list li:first');
      $first.animate({'margin-left': '-220px'}, 5000, "linear", function() {
        $first.remove().css({'margin-left': '0px'});
        $('#clients-list li:last').after($first);
      });
    } else {
    $('#clients-list li').stop();
    }
  }

  $(document).on({
    mouseover: function(){
      rotating = false; // turn off rotation when hovering
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
      rotating = true;
    }
  }, '.clients');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you clear the queue when you run .stop()

```
else {
    $('#clients-list li').stop(true, false);
}
```

You can learn more about .stop() [here](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrswchkp/2/)

Comment: I've got one more question - what about immediately start? Is there any function that allows to back to sliding?

Comment: You'd have to create your own function. There's nothing in JQuery that let's you pause and resume animations. But there are plugins like [this one](http://tobia.github.io/Pause/).

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me advices how to apply this to my code? It looks like I am js jquery dummy